# Making an app that changes background of the iPhone's spring board

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've tried to look over but couldn't find what I really want.

I'm planning to make something similar to [Icon Skins](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icon-skins-free-home-screen/id400677318?mt=8) app on app store; That is an app that can change your spring board background from a selection of images in a gallery.

I have a bit experience on coding with xcode and objective-c (I used cocos2d a while ago).

Could anyone give me a direction where should I start from? Is there any framework I could work my app on other than the iOS SDK itself?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are going to need is a server to load the images from and a way to display the images in the app. [This WWDC 2010 Session](http://developer.apple.com/itunes/?destination=adc.apple.com.4092349126.04109539109.4144345585?i=1699219987) is a great tutorial to use in terms of displaying the actual images. After the images are displayed, you will need a way for the user to save them to the camera roll and change it to their background, as there is no API that will automatically change the wallpaper (as far as I know).

Comment: So, is there a command line/functions in the SDK that let you change the background on your device? And is it possible to have this application change the background of the simulator (I want to try developing in iPhone simulator first)

Comment: Sadly, there isn't. However, there is a snippet of code that will save an image to your camera roll, and then the user can go to settings and change the newly saved image to their background/lock screen image. That is the method all apps of that kind use.

Comment: They changed the background from inside the app, though - Not exit the app and go to the setting -. So shouldn't there exist a snippet of code that will tell settings to set the background from a certain image on camera roll?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. One app I used (similar to the one you mentioned) used the method I described.

Comment: OK - my bad, I was wrong. You were right that the user need to exit the app and manually changes their background by going to camera roll.